# How do I drop rows in panadas based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   0 1 2 3 
0  C . . .
1  A . . .
3  B . . .
```

I have intentionally reset the indices so they are counting from 0 up. Using this:

```
cols = [0,3,19,20,21,22,23]
df = df.drop(df.columns[cols],axis=1)
df[5] = df[5].str[:4]
df = df.fillna('')
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
```

I am trying to drop all rows of the dataframe that contain A. However, I can't use the methods I've found because it says that it doesn't exist. I've tried:

```
df[df.0 != 'A']
df[df.'0' != 'A']
df[df.index[0] != 'A']
```

and

```
df.drop('A')
```

I keep getting the error:

```
KeyError: "['A'] not found in axis"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to delete all the rows in any column that contain 'A' or just any row containing 'A' from column 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete any row from any column containing 'A' then use below:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.columns) - 1):
    df = df[df[i] != 'A']
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't need it from any column so I just used the second line and those were the semantics that I was looking for. I replaced [i] with [0] and it removed all rows with A in column 0.